# How to conditionally display a tooltip in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, v-tooltip

I am trying to conditionally display a [`v-tooltip`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-tooltip) based on a Boolean. This is what I have currently:

```html
<div v-for="predefinedContentItem in getPredefinedContentCategoryItems(category.id)"
  :class="['category-item-content-wrapper', { 'not-clickable': isMainDialogClosed}]"
  v-tooltip.right="getPredefinedContentItemMessage(predefinedContentItem)"
  slot="content"
  :key="predefinedContentItem.id"
  @click="onPredefinedContentItemClick(predefinedContentItem, category.id)">
```

I'm not trying to dynamically display different tooltip text. I want to determine whether or not to display the actual tooltip. I've tried the following ternary with no success:

```html
<div v-for="predefinedContentItem in getPredefinedContentCategoryItems(category.id)"
  :class="['category-item-content-wrapper', { 'not-clickable': isMainDialogClosed}]"
  v-tooltip.right="isAutomotive ? getPredefinedContentItemMessage(predefinedContentItem) : null";
  slot="content"
  :key="predefinedContentItem.id"
  @click="onPredefinedContentItemClick(predefinedContentItem, category.id)">
```

Comment: which library are you using ? or you're creating that directive by yourself?

Comment: Yea its v-tooltip...

Answer (score 5):

You can pass to `v-tooltip` an object that takes extra options, and add the **`show` property** inside the directive like this:

```html
<div v-tooltip="{
  content: getPredefinedContentItemMessage(predefinedContentItem),
  show: isAutomotive,
  trigger: 'hover',
  placement: 'right',
}">
```

Answer (score 3):

```html
<div v-tooltip="{
   content: isAutomotive ? getPredefinedContentItemMessage(predefinedContentItem) : null,
   placement: 'right',
}">
```